# Refresh g:each tag via AJAX call in Grails

Tags: ajax, grails, each, gsp, grails-controller

I have a statistical panel which displays the last registered users. I want to implement a AJAX call to upload the panel without having to reload the full page.

**I have the following code in my view**:

```
<g:each in="${lastUsers}" var="user">
     <div class="mt-comments">
         <div class="mt-comment">
              <div class="mt-comment-img">
                  <g:if test="${user?.avatar}">
                       <img src="${createLink(controller:'controllerUser',
                       action:'image', id: user?.id)}" />
                  </g:if>
                  <g:else>
                       <img class="img-circle"
                       src="${resource(dir: 'img/profile', file: 'user_profile.png')}"/>
                 </g:else>
              </div>
              <div class="mt-comment-body">
                 <div class="mt-comment-info">
                     <span class="mt-comment-author">${user?.username}</span>
                     <span class="mt-comment-date">
                        <g:formatDate date="${user?.dateCreated}"/>
                     </span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="mt-comment-text">${user?.email}</div>
                    <div class="mt-comment-details">
                       <g:if test="${user?.enabled}">
                       <span class="mt-comment-status label label-sm label-success circle">
                       </g:if>
                       <g:else>
                       <span class="mt-comment-status label label-sm label-info circle">
                       </g:else>
                       <g:formatBoolean boolean="${user?.enabled}"/>
                       </span>
                       <ul class="mt-comment-actions">
                         <li>
                             <g:link controller="user" action="edit" id="${user?.id}">Edit</g:link>
                         </li>
                       </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</g:each>
```

Also, I have a button when it is clicked calls the AJAX function. The Ajax function receives the data successful in JSON format. From there, I don't know upload my g:each tag.

I have tried the remoteFunction of Grails to use the upload attribute, but an error appears: **No javascript provider is configured** and I have searched the solution but anything works me.

**The AJAX call:**

```
$('.button').click(function() {

     $.ajax({
       url: URL,     
       success: function(data) {

          console.log(data[index]);
          console.log(val.username);
          console.log(val.dateCreated);
          console.log(val.email);
          console.log(val.enabled);
          console.log(val.avatar);
          console.log(val.id);
       },
       error: function(){
       },
     });
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @JChap has the right answer below... you have to realize that all g: tags are rendered on the server side into HTML/javascript, etc.  And can only be re-rendered on the server.  Hence the result of the AJAX call below is HTML to replace the contents of the userComments div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of Using JSON Data, You can do this using grails templates and jQuery load method. Here is a quick POC.

**Template** (_userComments.gsp)

This will act as a reusable view which can be called via AJAX or can be included directly in other views.

```
<g:each in="${lastUsers}" var="user">
     <div class="mt-comments">
         .....
    </div>
</g:each>
```

**View** (main.gsp)

Our Main View.

```
<div class="userComments">
    <!-- When the Page is Loaded, We need render this without an Ajax Call -->
    <g:render template="userComments"  model="['lastUsers':lastUsers]"/>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.button').click(function() {
   $( ".userComments" ).load( "user/userComments" );
});
```

**Controller**

We are defining two methods one for the main view and one for the ajax call.

```
def index() {
    def lastUsers = User.list();
    render(view:'main', model: [lastUsers: lastUsers])
}

// Ajax Call
def userComments() {
    def lastUsers = User.list(); // what ever your fetch logic is
    render(template:'userComments', model: [lastUsers: lastUsers])
}
```